# SwiftUI translate and rotate view with matchedGeometryEffect strange behavior

Tags: swift, animation, swiftui, rotation

I'm trying to simulate dealing cards in SwiftUI. I'm testing with one card, and the goal is to animate the card in the center (image1) to one of the sides (image2). I would like that the animation would rotate and translate the card simultaneously, but with this code the card rotates immediately without animation and then it translates animatedly. Any idea to get the rotation and translation effects simultaneously into the animation?

[image: Card in the center]

[image: Card in one side]

```
import SwiftUI

struct Card: Identifiable {
    var id: String {
        return value
    }
    let value: String
    var dealt: Bool = false
}

struct CardView: View {
    let card: Card
    var flipped: Bool = false
    
    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            Color.white
            Text("\(card.value)")
            .padding(4)
            Color.red.opacity(flipped ? 0.0 : 1.0)
        }
        .border(.black, width: 2)
    }
}

struct CardsTableView: View {
    @Namespace private var dealingNamespace
    
    @State var card = Card(value: "1", dealt: false)
    
    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            Rectangle()
                .foregroundColor(.clear)
                .border(.black, width: 2)
                .padding(10)
            VStack {
                ZStack {
                    centerCard
                    lateralCard
                }
                Spacer()
                Button {
                    withAnimation(.linear(duration: 1)) {
                        card.dealt.toggle()
                    }
                } label: {
                    Text("Deal")
                }
                .padding()
            }
        }
    }
    
    var centerCard: some View {
        VStack {
            Spacer()
            if !card.dealt {
                CardView(card: card)
                    .frame(width: 40, height: 70)
                    .matchedGeometryEffect(id: card.id, in: dealingNamespace)
                    .transition(AnyTransition.asymmetric(insertion: .opacity, removal: .identity))
            }
            Spacer()
        }
    }
    
    var lateralCard: some View {
        HStack {
            Spacer()
            if card.dealt {
                CardView(card: card)
                    .matchedGeometryEffect(id: card.id, in: dealingNamespace)
                    .frame(width: 40, height: 70)
                    .rotationEffect(.degrees(-90))
                    .transition(AnyTransition.asymmetric(insertion: .identity, removal: .opacity))
            }
        }
        .padding(.trailing, 20)
    }
}
```

Comment: I would suggest using only one card and moving that single card to another position.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `matchedGeometryEffect` modifier doesn't know about the `rotationEffect` modifier, so neither view's rotation is animated during the transition. I'll explain how to get the animation you want in two ways: using transitions and using “slots”. Both solutions produce this animation:

[image: animation of card rotating and sliding between top and side positions]

### Using transitions

You can use a custom `.modifier` transition to animate the rotation. I wouldn't do it this way, but since it has a similar structure as the code you posted, I'll explain it first.

For the sake of this answer, let's simplify `CardView`:

```
struct CardView: View {
    var body: some View {
        Text("C")
            .foregroundColor(.black)
            .padding()
            .background(Color.white)
            .border(Color.black, width: 1)
    }
}
```

To animate rotation, we need a `ViewModifier` type that applies the rotation effect:

```
struct CardRotationModifier: ViewModifier {
    var angle: Angle
    
    func body(content: Content) -> some View {
        content.rotationEffect(angle)
    }
}
```

Here's `CardTableView`:

```
struct CardTableView: View {
    @Namespace var namespace
    @State var isSide = false
    
    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            VStack {
                if !isSide {
                    topCard
                }
                Spacer()
            }
            HStack {
                Spacer()
                if isSide {
                    sideCard
                }
            }
        }
        .padding()
        .background(Color.mint)
        .onTapGesture {
            withAnimation(.linear) {
                isSide.toggle()
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And finally here are the top and side card views:

```
extension CardTableView {
    var topCard: some View {
        CardView()
            .matchedGeometryEffect(id: 0, in: namespace)
            .transition(
                .modifier(
                    active: CardRotationModifier(angle: .degrees(90)),
                    identity: CardRotationModifier(angle: .zero)))
    }
    
    var sideCard: some View {
        CardView()
            .matchedGeometryEffect(id: 0, in: namespace)
            .transition(
                .modifier(
                    active: CardRotationModifier(angle: .zero),
                    identity: CardRotationModifier(angle: .degrees(90))))
    }
}
```

Note that the side card doesn't have a `.rotationEffect`. Instead, both cards have a transition that applies `CardRotationModifier`. SwiftUI applies the `active` modifier at the start of an entrance transition and the end of an exit transition. It applies the `identity` modifier at the end of an entrance transition, the start of an exit transition, and the entire time the view is “at rest” (present and not transitioning). So the top card normally has rotation zero, and the side card normally has rotation 90°, and each card is animated to the other's rotation during a transition.

What I don't like about this solution is that the transitions are configured specifically for moving a card between the top and side positions. The transition on the top position knows about the rotation of the side position, and vice versa. So what if you want to add a left-side position with a rotation of -90°? You've got a problem. Now you need to dynamically set the transition of each position based on where the card is moving from and to. Every position needs to know details of every other position, so it can be O(N) work to add another position.

### Using slots

Instead, I would use what I think of as “slots”: put a hidden view at each possible position (“slot”) of a card. Then, use a view with a persistent identity to draw the card, and tell that persistent view to match the geometry of whichever slot it should occupy.

So, we need a way to identify each slot:

```
enum Slot: Hashable {
    case top
    case side
}
```

Now `CardTableView` lays out a subview for each slot, and a view for the card:

```
struct CardTableView: View {
    @Namespace var namespace
    @State var isSide = false
    
    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            topSlot
            sideSlot
            card
        }
        .padding()
        .background(Color.mint)
        .onTapGesture {
            withAnimation(.linear) {
                isSide.toggle()
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Here are the slot subviews:

```
extension CardTableView {
    var topSlot: some View {
        VStack {
            CardView()
                .hidden()
                .matchedGeometryEffect(id: Slot.top, in: namespace)
            Spacer()
        }
    }
    
    var sideSlot: some View {
        HStack {
            Spacer()
            CardView()
                .hidden()
                .matchedGeometryEffect(id: Slot.side, in: namespace)
        }
    }
}
```

And here is the card subview:

```
extension CardTableView {
    var card: some View {
        CardView()
            .rotationEffect(isSide ? .degrees(90): .zero)
            .matchedGeometryEffect(
                id: isSide ? Slot.side : Slot.top,
                in: namespace, isSource: false)
    }
}
```

Notice that now there are no transitions anywhere, and none of the slots knows anything about the other slots. If you want to add another slot, it's a matter of defining another slot subview, adding that new slot subview to the `CardTableView` `ZStack`, and updating the `card` subview to know how to pose itself in the new slot. None of the existing slot subviews are affected. It's O(1) work to add a new slot.